# ¿Como filtrar los datos en StringBuilder?

Tags: java, android, string

tengo un `StringBuilder` donde hago una lista de las propiedades que el usuario estableció y me gustaría poder filtrar ciertas claves como por ejemplo un texto `"null"` ya que ese texto representa a la propiedad y al valor que ha sido restablecido, y por ende no debe figurar, aquí les comparto un fragmento de mi codigo:

```
sb2.append(attr.key+=+attr.value);
```

Recuerda que el `attr.key` representa el nombre del atributo y `attr.value` representa el valor del atributo.

Lo que yo quiero hacer es lo siguiente: supongamos que el usuario estableció attributos a un `view` en general y después borró esos atributos, al borrar esos atributos yo les dejo con valor, llamemoslo `"a"`. Cuando el usuario verifica las propiedades también aparece las que se borró (que aparecen con el valor). Me gustaría saber como aplicar la función `for()` para añadir solamente aquellos atributos que no tengan el valor `"a"`. Muchas gracias!

Les muestro un fragmento de la salida de los valores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La parte de `android:background` representa al `attr.key` y el `"null"` representa al `attr.value`. El usuario al borrar este atributo en teoría no debería de filtrarse ahí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes filtrar de esta forma para que no agregue los atributos con valor "null":

```
if(!attr.value.equals("null"){
   sb2.append(attr.key+=+attr.value);
}
```